# How can I create a keyboard shortcut for screen brightness as the default <F4> and <F5> don't work?

Tags: shortcut-keys, brightness, function-keys

I'm using an ASUS laptop and running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from an SSD. With Windows, I can press <kbd>F4</kbd> and <kbd>F5</kbd> to adjust the brightness, but it's not possible while running Ubuntu. Keyboard shortcuts from settings doesn't allow me to set brightness shortcuts. Is there a way?

Someone mentioned this:
[Brightness shortcut doesn't work right on an Acer Aspire 5750G](https://askubuntu.com/a/276270/1100108), but I don't know how to save terminal commands.

Comment: Adding "ANSWERED" to the question title or adding the solution to the question itself is not how we mark a question as "answered" here at Ask Ubuntu. Instead you should ["accept" the most helpful answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) (by clicking the tick (✓) next to it) to indicate you've found a working solution and also so that others may more easily find it in the future.

Answer (score 3):

If the <kbd>F4</kbd> or <kbd>F5</kbd> keys act as just function keys, you need to use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> instead to trigger the brightness decrease/increase feature.

You would probably be able to change how the function keys work (i.e. only function keys vs. <kbd>Fn</kbd> + function keys) from your BIOS settings (depending on the laptop).